# FBX Exporter Animation Artefacts

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I am using the FBX Exporter to export animations from Blender but I see strange animation artefacts when playing back the FBX with Autodesk's FBX Review

At first I thought it might be FBX Review, but then on importing the FBX back into Blender those artefacts are also clearly visible in Blender.

Below are gif versions of the Blender and FBX Review for a simple rig.

In the Blender version the feet do not move at all.  In the FBX version, the feet are continuously moving and you can see a jitter at the beginning, middle and end of the animation.

[image: Blender]

[image: FBX Review]

I am using Blender 2.78a with FBX Exporter that comes with it.

Has anyone seen this problem or could shed some light on a possible solution?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what causes the problem, but I fixed it by restarting from scratch.  I appended just the mesh from the original blend file into a new one then I rebuilt the armatures.  The resulting exported fbx then did not suffer from the jitter problem.

Not a great answer, but I found the following which could be the reasons for not working in the first place:

1. Make sure scale is applied to everything before you start building the armatures.
2. It seems that the fbx exporter does not handle scaling in the animations well, so don't have any scaling in your animations.
3. The fbx exporter seems to ignore the objects' origins and uses the "world" origin instead.  To avoid any problems, set all the objects' origins to the "world" origin.

You may be able to get away with just applying these steps without having to rebuild the armature.

I have since then always followed these steps on new projects and it has worked every time.

I would like to hear from others if this works for them.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you going from Blender 2.79b to Unity 2017.1 using FBX 7.4.
I create two armatures to avoid many problems and have a performance control on parenting and hierarchies. One armature is for animation and the othe is deform and to export. The second follows the first one using Transform Constraint.

Have you solved the problem? Do you find something about this problem?